# Python: Misleading Documentation of csv module Dialect class

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) states that the default value of `Dialect.delimiter` is `','`. However, when I try to print, it returns `None`.

```
>>> print(csv.Dialect.delimiter)
None
```

> Dialect.delimiter A one-character string used to separate fields. It
>     defaults to ','.

Comment: @Aran-Fey is there any possible explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is default value when you creating your own dialect.

```
import csv

csv.register_dialect('my_dialect')
dialect = csv.get_dialect('my_dialect')
print(dialect.delimiter)
```

Comment: @Syzmon but I can also create a dialect by inheriting from `Dialect` class. In this case, however, I have to set every formatting arguments. Clearly, this is a conflict,

Comment: This only holds true when using `register_dialect()` function.

Comment: yes, but you have to register dialect before you will use it

Comment: No, you can assign the class object directly to the `dialect` argument.

Answer (score 2):

That's the default value when you create a new `Dialect`. You can get a dialect instance (an inmutable one if you're using Python 3.x) with `csv.get_dialect()` and register your own using `csv.register_dialect`. You can also just subclass `Dialect` and get on with it.

The documentation may seem unclear if you just read that line, but a few lines above you can see that:

> To make it easier to specify the format of input and output records, specific formatting parameters are grouped together into dialects. A dialect is a **subclass** of the Dialect class having a set of specific methods and a single validate() method.

Doing a simple `help(csv.Dialect)` in the REPL confirms that subclassing is a must when working with this class.

```
class Dialect(builtins.object)
 |  Describe a CSV dialect.
 |
 |  This must be subclassed (see csv.excel).  Valid attributes are:
 |  delimiter, quotechar, escapechar, doublequote, skipinitialspace,
 |  lineterminator, quoting.
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __init__(self)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |
 |  delimiter = None
 |
 |  doublequote = None
 |
 |  escapechar = None
 |
 |  lineterminator = None
 |
 |  quotechar = None
 |
 |  quoting = None
 |
 |  skipinitialspace = None
```